# Calling grand-parent function in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, super, es6-class

I get this class inheritance structure:

```
class GrandParent{
  funcA(){
    console.log('GrandParent');
  }
}
class Parent extends GrandParent{
  funcA(){
    console.log('Parent');
  }
}
class Child extends Parent{
  funcA(){
    console.log('Child');
    // how to call funcA of GrandParent -> super.super.funcA()
  }
}
```

Question is: how can I call GrandParent.funcA() from Child.funcA()?

> Child
>
> GrandParent

Should be logged on console.

Thanks;

Comment: You can call it over super function

Comment: If I do that I call Parent.funcA(), I want to call GrandParent.func(A)

Comment: So, I guess there is no straight forward way. Thanks

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can call it via `new GrandParent().funcA();`

```js
class GrandParent {
  funcA() {
    console.log('GrandParent');
  }
}
class Parent extends GrandParent {
  funcA() {
    console.log('Parent');
  }
}
class Child extends Parent {
  funcA() {
    console.log('Child');
    new GrandParent().funcA();
  }
}

const child = new Child();
child.funcA();
```

Answer (score 3):

This is contradictory: you've overriden `GranParent.funcA` with a new implementation. If you need what `GranParent.funcA` does, probably you'll need to decompose your code a bit, and override `Child.funcA` as needed depending on your actual use case.

Take advantage of polymorphism:

```js
class GrandParent {
  doStuff() {
    console.log('some stuff')
  }

  funcA() {
    this.doStuff()
    console.log('GrandParent')
  }
}

class Parent extends GrandParent {
  funcA() {
    console.log('Parent')
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  funcA() {
    this.doStuff()
    console.log('child')
  }
}

const child = new Child()
child.funcA()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want to use `super` keyword it's possible, but you'll need to point to appropriate prototype. In other words you should go through `__proto__` object chain manually.

```js
class Level1 {
  me() { console.log('Level1'); }
}

class Level2 extends Level1 {
  me() { console.log('Level2'); }
}

class Level3 extends Level2 {
  me() { 
    super.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.me();
    //      ^         ^         ^ reference to Level1 prototype
    //      |         | reference to Level2 prototype 
    //      | reference to Level3 prototype
    console.log('Level3'); 
  }
}

const foo = new Level3();
foo.me();
```

But as it's said before, probably it worth to rethink the logic to avoid such structure in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the function using the super keyword. You need to call the super in parent function to point the funcA in class Grandparent.

```js
class GrandParent{
  funcA(){
    console.log('GrandParent');
  }
}
class Parent extends GrandParent{
  funcA(){
    console.log('Parent');
    super.funcA();
  }
}
class Child extends Parent{
  funcA(){
    console.log('Child');
    super.funcA();

  }
}

var x = new Child();
x.funcA();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
GrandParent.prototype.funcA.call(this)
```

```js
class GrandParent {
  funcA() {
    console.log('GrandParent');
  }
}

class Parent extends GrandParent {
  funcA() {
    console.log('Parent');
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  funcA() {
    console.log('Child');
    // how to call funcA of GrandParent -> super.super.funcA()
    GrandParent.prototype.funcA.call(this);
    // in this case you can also run it without your context as it is not used
    GrandParent.prototype.funcA(); 
  }
}

new Child().funcA();
```